# How to repack zip files without using tmp dir?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a lot of zip files that I need to repack/recompress in order to work around a bug in MediaWiki 0.1.18.

I can do it with

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *zip; do
   cd tmp
   rm -rf *
   unzip ../"$f"
   zip -r ../"$f" *
   cd ..
done
```

but is there a way to do this e.g. with pipes or perhaps a zip option?

Comment: `man zip` as far as I can tell doesn't mention anything about this, but I could repack the files using a tmp dir, but I really would like to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. If you send some bits to zip it doesn't have a way to know when one file ends and a new one begins.

Actually you can write your own program to do the job but from your description it seems like an overkill. Also you are not telling what exactly bug are you fixing so other workarounds cannot be suggested.

Comment: I think `you can't` is a bit strong here. There is more than one way to do it. True that a naive pipe does not know the filename, but a find -execdir or simple bash-script with a loop does.

Comment: Please show that *simple* script. To me the simplest method to perform that without using temporary files/dirs is to use some scripting language with some zip library. I also can't see any zip option to read data from stdin. But I think something can be crafted with the <(command) bash syntax, but will be slow dealing with one file at a time. And will be very ugly (as a code).

Comment: `echo "This will be zipped" | tee x | zip >x.zip; unzip -p x.zip >y; diff x y;` - x.zip will be the zipped version of x, x and y will be equal. Really, zip can work with STDIN, STDOUT and pipes fine!

Comment: btw it is sad that a non-answer has 6 ups and the answer that tells the unpleasant truth has only 0...

Comment: excuse me but this code is misleading. If you do unzip -t x.zip, you will see that the file name is actually `-'. How would you add more files to that archive? btw good to know zip can actually read data form stdin although although with very limited usability.

Comment: My dear, it is because your answer starts with "you can't". Clearly, if you can zip from STDIN and to STDOUT, you can. If you have multiple files, you will indeed need a solution for the filenames, like a find-execdir or a bash-script.

Comment: The question was very clear that Sandra wanted to re-compress random archives. It was not about compressing one file on stdin. Additionally your example starts with some data. You need to start with a zip file and end with a zip file with the same content. You didn't(can't) show that. So my answer is correct. *You can't.* And I say that with some programming it is possible but not going to write such a program. On the contrary your answer is useless but got the credit. Your answer wrong - ok. You got the credit - ok. But telling others answers are wronger - not ok with me. I stop here.

Answer (score 3):

```
gzip -d -c old.gz | gzip >new.gz
```

Comment: It is real `.zip` files I have, and sadly not `.gz`.

Comment: Well, what program do you open to use .zip files? Are `zip` and `unzip` installed? Or 7zip?

Comment: Yes, zip, unzip, and 7z are all there.

Comment: Then I propose you use zip and unzip instead of gzip and gzip -d :] `zip` also supports a `-c` parameter to redirect output to STDOUT, which you pipe into STDIN. Put that in your bash script and add the file names.

Comment: With `unzip old.zip | zip -c >new.zip` am I getting `zip error: Nothing to do`.

Comment: unzip needs to be told it needs to zip to stdout - that is where the `-c``  parameter comes in. Else it just transforms the file.

Comment: Same happens with `unzip -c old.zip | zip -c >new.zip`

Comment: It is not possible to pipe the output from zip as zip doesn't contain a single stream but files and a basic filesystem. Think of it more like tar than gzip.

Answer (score 3):

There is a utility called [AdvanceCOMP](http://advancemame.sourceforge.net/comp-readme.html) that does exactly what you're looking for. It recompresses ZIP and GZ files (and some others) without intermediary extraction to disk. (I do believe that the mechanism used is to decompress the data and recompress it, but that does not require writing files to disk or regenerating metadata.)

Comment: couldn't get advzip to work on a backup.zip - says there was a CRC error. The zip file tested fine. Maybe this utility is specific to MAME?

Comment: Advzip works quite well for me. I can't say what caused the CRC error you experienced

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but it may be helpfull for those who come later:

`zipsplit -n 2147483648` will repack zip upto 2GiB without extraction. But as this command is for splitting zip files, there is no option to overwrite original or specify output file, only output directory.